# In a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded ring with unity, $1$ is homogeneous of degree zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, graded-rings

> Suppose I have a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded ring (commutative) $A$ with unity. I am sure
>   that the unity $1 \in A$ has degree $0$. I was wondering how could one show that?

(I am guessing we don't have to take it as an axiom...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $1=a_p+\cdots+a_q$ with $p\le q$, $a_p\ne 0$ and $a_q\ne 0$. It is easily seen that we can't have $q<0$ or $p>0$, otherwise multiply $1=a_p+\cdots+a_q$ with an arbitrary homogeneous element and get that every homogeneous element of $A$ is $0$, a contradiction.

Then $q\ge 0$ and $p\le 0$, and assume that at least one of the two inequalities is strict. Say $q>0$. From $1=a_p+\cdots+a_q$ we get $x=xa_p+\cdots+xa_q$ for every homogeneous $x\in A$, hence $xa_q=0$ for every homogeneous $x\in A$. In particular, $a_ia_q=0$ for all $i=p,\dots,q$, hence $1\cdot a_q=0$, a contradiction.

Conclusion: $p=q=0$, and therefore $1\in A_0$.

Comment: How do you know $1$ is homogeneous?

Comment: @user170778 $1$ is a (finite) *sum* of homogeneous elements and the multiplication is distributive with respect to the addition.

Answer (score 1):

If $a\in A_n$ is of degree $n$, what is the degree of $a^2$?

Comment: Is the degree in graded rings defined for elements that are non-homogeneous as well? (How do we know $1$ is homogeneous?)

Comment: Hmm... Didn't think to prove that $1$ is homogenous... I have to think a bit more about that. The Wikipedia article on grades rings says that $0$ and $1$ are homogenous of degree $0$, but I don't know how to prove it just yet.

Comment: I am very sure it is true, but I got stuck there...

Comment: Well, there is a unit element of $A_0$. It's probably easiest to prove that that unit works in $A$ as well (the fact that $A_n$ is an $A_0$ module might help)

Comment: hmmm.. How do we know that there is a unit in $A_0$? Thanks~